# Sublime text auto-complete overrides snippet

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have a `console.log()` snippet for Sublime Text that fires when you type 'c' then tab trigger, however if there is code that starts with 'c' somewhere on the page auto-complete overrides the console.log snippet. Is there a way around this or should I just add another modifier for my snippet?

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[console.log($1);$0]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>c</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.js</scope>
    <description>Log</description>
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html it mentions that snippets always lose against a fuzzy match. Since the buffer contents are included in the auto completion, I'd suggest modifying your snippet to include a few more characters.